# fluent nhibernate как обновить данные не используя DML-стиль и не читая их пердварительно из базы

Tags: c#, orm, nhibernate

Подскажите кто хорошо знаком с Fluent NHibernate.
Допустим есть таблица mytable содержащая колонки id, name, time.
Для неё описана модель и мапинг

```
public class MyTable
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual int Time { get; set; }
}
public class MyTableMap : ClassMap<MyTable>
{
    public MyTableMap()
    {
        Table("mytable");
        Id(x => x.Id, "id");
        Map(x => x.Name, "name");
        Map(x => x.Time, "time");
        DynamicUpdate();
    }
}
```

Допустим мне надо обновить данные в поле name. Я могу сделать это например так:

```
using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    using (var tr = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var data = session.Get<MyTable>(10L);
        data.Name = "new name";
        tr.Commit();
    }
}
```

Но этот код сгенерирует 2 запроса select и update (примерно таких):

```
select * from mytable where id = 10;
update mytable set name = 'new name' where id = 10;
```

Я могу обновить данные по другому:

```
using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenStatelessSession())
{
    using (var tr = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        session.CreateQuery("update MyTable set name = :name where id = :id")
                    .SetString("name", "new name")
                    .SetInt64("id", 10L)
                    .ExecuteUpdate();
        tr.Commit();
    }
}
```

В этом случае будет сгенерирован один запрос update, но теперь данные для формирования запроса помещены в строку и если допущена ошибка, то на стадии компиляции я ни чего не увижу, только в рантайме. А если ни дай бог таблица mytable будет изменена, то придется проверять "вручную" все запросы связанные с этой таблицей.
Вопрос, существует ли возможность писать update запросы обращаясь не к полям в базе, а к свойствам которые я объявил в модели ? Что то типа такого:

```
session.Filter(x => x.Id == 10L).Update(x => x.Name = "new name")
```

Comment: У вас пет-проект на 10 строчек кода? Я почему спрашиваю - на крупных проектах никто не экономит запросы, жертвуя стабильностью. Это сейчас у вас имя сущности можно апдейтить через SQL, а если сущность будет валидировать допустимость имени, то вариант останется только один - через получение сущности из базы и её обновление.